# Solutions or workaound for Visual Studio conditional breakpoint slowness

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using a conditional breakpoint to determine when a `C#` `DateTime` variable is greater than a certain time.  This breakpoint will be checked approximately 50,000 times in a run.

my conditional breakpoint looks like:

```
quote.Time > new DateTime(2014,2,4,3,59,0)
```

Without this conditional break point my test run takes about 15 seconds.  With the conditional breakpoint it takes 45 minutes.

Is there anything I can do to help speed this without modifying the code I'm debugging to add an assert or conditional?

Is there anyway to make it calculate the DateTime variable only once?  Or is this more of an architectural issue with how conditional breakpoints are implemented in the IDE?

Comment: Have you tried instantiating the `new DateTime(2014,2,4,3,59,0)` into a variable outside of the loop and having the condition use it? This would tell you whether the delay is on the `new Date`

Comment: Is it inside a loop? You can define new Datetime outside the loop if it is to a variable.

Comment: @Adrian,  there isn't an inner or tight loop here.  The code is called for each quote event.  I can make the DateTime a member variable as a one time hack, but this doesn't seem to get me much performance back.

Comment: How many times is the break point actually hit with the condition in your runs?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, if by hit you mean actually breaks, then the answer is just once.  If you mean how many times does it have to be checked, then the answer is about 50,000.

Comment: I meant breaks - I'm interested in why there would be *so much* slow down. I want to do something simple to see if I see the same behavior across Visual Studio versions/computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently conditional break points being very slow is a  known issue.  See: http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=visual+studio+conditional+breakpoint+slow

Since I know how many times my function will be called, deterministic simulation, I ended up using visual studio's `Hit Count` breakpoint feature.

This allowed me to not have to hack up the code with an `if` statement and iterate faster if my break condition changed.

Answer (score 8):

why don't you stop using a conditional break point and change the code until you have debugged it. so the code would become something like:

```
int dummyx = 0;
if (quote.Time > new DateTime (2014,2,4,3,59,0 )
{

dummyx++; // put normal break point here!

}
```

This will run much faster.

Comment: sure, I can.  I just figured it was worth asking if there is a better way before I hack up the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just for debugging purposes I'd say create a new if-statement and a dummy variable (like int i = 0;) and set the breakpoint on that line. Then just step into / step through the rest of the code.. Just for testing, you can always just remove those 1-2 lines of code after testing.

The if-statement (logically) containing:
 `if (quote.Time > new DateTime(2014,2,4,3,59,0)) { int i=0; }`